# BI Publisher Report NaN value displayed

Tags: xml, rtf, bi-publisher

I face some prob which is my field come out with NaN value.
How can I replace NaN value with 0.

Current 
Total Unit : `<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,'SWOunits')?>`

Output : NaN

Answer (score 0):

NaN =  "Not a Number"

You have two options:

## Safe divide

Try using the "safe-div" function. Safe divide function returns a specified value if the result of the function is NaN.

```
xdoxslt:sdiv(String dividend, String divisor, String fallOver)
```

Examples:

`<?xdoxslt:sdiv(10,0, '0')?>` would yield '0'

`<?xdoxslt:sdiv(10,0, 'None')?>` would yield 'None'

## If Statement

To define behavior when the element is present and the value is not null, use the following:

```
<?if:element_name!=' '?> desired behavior <?end if?>
```

To define behavior when the element is present, but is null, use the following:

```
<?if:element_name and element_name="?> desired behavior <?end if?>
```

To define behavior when the element is not present, use the following:

```
<?if:not(element_name)?> desired behavior <?end if?>
```